# Unmanaged package postinstaller not running

Tags: unmanaged-package

I wrote a post-installer which is aimming to deploy some DB records once users install our unmanaged pkg.

The data is not deployed to the database as expect.

However, we can execute the method manually.

E.g: TestTemplatesInstaller.setupTestAdminConfiguration();

everthing will work fine by doing so.

I believe we missed some setting for the installhandler?

Any idea?

```
    global class TestTemplatesInstaller implements InstallHandler {

        global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
            setupTestAdminConfiguration();
        }


        global static void setupTestAdminConfiguration() {
          .......


        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you set the post install option on the package?

Comment: @Eric is there any way to setup post install option for the unmanaged pkg?

Answer (score 4):

Post Install only works for the managed packages and do not run for the unmanaged packages .Check the official docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=apex_post_install_script.htm&type=0) .

Comment: then, that's too bad. is there any workaround can execute a script when users install the unmanaged pkg? thanks so much!

Comment: please open a new post for any follo wup questions. Thanks!